# Is there a way to navigate to a different screen from the menu built in my Parent Component?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to add a simple customized navigation menu to my react-native app, but the issue that I am coming across right now is that I can't seem to find a way to navigate to the selected menu items corresponding screen. I tried the normal `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')`, but it seems that there is no navigation prop, which makes sense because in my app I am assuming that the prop for navigation is passed down to the screens from my `app.js` through the use of `<AppContainer />`.

I have tried using the `MainNavigator` object in my `App.js` but it doesn't seem to be working and doesn't have a navigate function or anything like that.

I have also tried changing the structure of my render function in `App.js` a little bit but it still does not seem to be having much of an effect.

This is my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import {
createStackNavigator,
createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// SCREEN
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';
import CostAnalysis from './screens/CostAnalysis';
import DriverLog from './screens/DriverLog';

// SIDE MENU
import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu';

// REDUX IMPORTS
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { recordReducer } from './reducers/recordReducer';
import { databaseReducer } from './reducers/databaseReducer';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: MainScreen},
  DriverLog: {screen: DriverLog},
  CostAnalysis: {screen: CostAnalysis},
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

const rootReducer = combineReducers(
  {records: recordReducer,
     database: databaseReducer});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const menu = (<View style={{
      backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', 
      alignContent: 'center', 
      textAlign: 'center', height: '100%', width: '100%', paddingTop: '40%'}}>
      <Text style={styles.menuTitle}>{'S K I P\nD R I V E R\nL O G'}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}}>
        <Text style={styles.menuItem}>HOME</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {MainNavigator.navigate('DriverLog')}}>
        <Text style={styles.menuItem}>DRIVING LOG</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>);

    return (
      <SideMenu menu={menu} >
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppContainer />
        </Provider>
      </SideMenu>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  menuTitle: {
    marginBottom: 60,
    fontSize: 40,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#e74c3c'
  },
  menuItem: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 26,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
}

export default (App);
```

Ideally I don't have to re-structure my entire app as I have made a lot of progress in other areas, but I would really like the menu to simply link to the correct places.

I'm still very new to react-native so I really don't know what else to try. If anyone can give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

PS: See a picture of the menu to illustrate what I mean
[Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25aEm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement the constructor

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  } 
}
```

**or**

if you are using a drawer use it as a separate component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

class SideDrawer extends Component{
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  } 
render(){
   return(
<View style={{
      backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', 
      alignContent: 'center', 
      textAlign: 'center', height: '100%', width: '100%', paddingTop: '40%'}}>
      <Text style={styles.menuTitle}>{'S K I P\nD R I V E R\nL O G'}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}}>
        <Text style={styles.menuItem}>HOME</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {MainNavigator.navigate('DriverLog')}}>
        <Text style={styles.menuItem}>DRIVING LOG</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
}
}

export default sideDrawer
```

then in your navigator

```
  const HomeNavigator = StackNavigator(
  Home: {screen: MainScreen},
  DriverLog: {screen: DriverLog},
  CostAnalysis: {screen: CostAnalysis},
    }

const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: HomeNavigator,
  },
}, {
  contentComponent: sideDrawer,
  drawerWidth: width * .7,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the solution in my use case was actually to move the `SideMenu` component wrapper to the individual screens for which they were being used. This way I could access the `navigator` just like I am used to but also I can limit the `SideMenu` to only be used on screens where it is necessary for my app. I simply created a custom component in this case so that I could keep my styling and functionality consistent across screens for which I would like to have the `SideMenu` and then just import each component to the screens I needed and fill in props for certain aspects.